# Node.js MySQL connection management with HTTP Server

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I do understand that one should be closing mysql connections on existing node process. But with long live connections like Http servers things are little different and i seems to be confusing myself.

With node-mysql (npm package) i will be doing `connection.end();` in order to end connection with mysql.

Now the questions is should i be doing it every time before sending the final response to http client or how it should work ?

### For Example

```
// assuming express app
app.get("/users",function(req,res){
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM users",function(err,rows){
    connection.end();
    if(error){
      res.send(error);
    }else{
       res.send(rows); 
    }
  })
})
```

Personally in a huge project it is hard to maintain `connection.end();` statements for every Http request. So i am interested in knowing what are the best ways to manage `mysql` connection in NodeJs HTTP Servers.

Comment: Why are you closing them? Just leave it open.

Comment: Look into using the built-in [connection pool](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#pooling-connections) too.

Comment: If i do not close it , it fills the connection pool and start throwing errors

Comment: @robertklep connection pool also recommends to release the pool after query. So here's the issue it is hard to maintain references to check whether i have released it or not.

Comment: @AmanVirk if you use `pool.query()` instead of `connection.query()` you don't have to release yourself, it will be done automatically.